# Angular JS - $watch changes made in directive from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, watch, angular-controller

I'm trying to $watch changes that happen in directive scope and add objects to an array if they have been changed. The edit functionality is in the directive scope but the save functionality is outside of the directive scope i.e., save is called from controller scope. I'm using a shared object to with two way binding to access the objects that have been edited in the directive scope. The edits are being saved correctly but I need to filter out any objects that have not been changed. I don't understand why the changes aren't reflected in $watch.

// controller

```
vm.accessor = {};
getGlobalConfigs();
$scope.$watch('vm.accessor.globalConfigs', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('config changed');
});
function getGlobalConfigs() {
    vehicleConfigurationsFactory.getGlobalConfigs()
    .then(function (data) {
        vm.accessor.globalConfigs = data;
    });
}
```

// directive

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('vehicleConfigurationsModule')
.directive('globalConfig', globalConfig);

    function globalConfig() {

    var directive = {
        link: link,
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: 'app/vehicle-configurations/global-config-tr.html',
        scope: {
          confkey: '@',
          confvalue: '=',
          confprecedence: '=',
          confdescription: '=',
          accessor: '='
        }
    }

    return directive;

    function link(scope, el, attrs, controller) {
      scope.master = {
        confvalue: scope.confvalue,
        confprecedence: scope.confprecedence,
        confdescription: scope.confdescription
      };
      scope.disabled = true;
      scope.precedenceOptions = [
        {value: "GLOBAL"},
        {value: "VEHICLE"}
      ];
      scope.selectedOption = {value: scope.confprecedence};
      scope.edit = function() {
        scope.disabled = false;
        scope.accessor.disabled = false;
      };
      scope.cancel = function() {
        scope.disabled = true;
        scope.accessor.disabled = true;
        scope.confvalue = scope.master.confvalue;
        scope.confprecedence = scope.master.confprecedence;
        scope.confdescription = scope.master.confdescription;
      };
      scope.setPrecedence = function(value) {
        scope.confprecedence = value;
      };
    }

 }


})();
```

// directive instance

```
<tr ng-repeat="config in vm.accessor.globalConfigs" global-config confkey="{{ config.confKey }}" confvalue="config.confValue" confprecedence="config.precedence" confdescription="config.description" accessor="vm.accessor"></tr>
```

// directive template

```
<td ng-model="config.confKey">{{ confkey }}</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="confvalue" ng-disabled="disabled">
</td>
<td>
    <select class="form-control" ng-options="option.value for option in precedenceOptions track by option.value"
ng-model="selectedOption" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-change="setPrecedence(selectedOption.value)"></select>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="confdescription" ng-disabled="disabled">
</td>
<td>
    <a ng-show="disabled" role="button" translate="{{ 'vehicle-configurations.edit' }}" ng-click="edit()"></a>
    <a ng-show="!disabled" role="button" translate="{{ 'vehicle-configurations.cancel' }}" ng-click="cancel()"></a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like kind of an odd way to do this, however I think you just need to tell your watch to watch the objects INSIDE globalConfigs like this:

```
$scope.$watch('vm.accessor.globalConfigs', function(newValue, oldValue) {
     console.log('config changed');
},true);
```

Note the third param to $watch ",true" which tells watch to "deep watch".

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Do you have any suggestions to improve the code? I'm still new to using directives.

Comment: Typically if I need to have a directive call something outside in my controller I'll pass in the function as a parameter to the directive. That way you can have your $watch inside the directive and when it triggers it calls the function you passed into the directive.  This helps keep the directive code self-contained so you can easily re-use it.